# Rails Error "expected ...model.rb to define Model"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model

```
class ItemController < ApplicationController

  def create
    item = current_user.items.build(params[:presentstem])
    item.created_at = Time.now
    item.save!
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy

  end

end
```

And my form in views/home/index/html.erb to add an item

```
<div id="add_item">
    <p>Add a new item</p>
    <% form_for Item.new do |f| %>
        <div id="add_item_container">
        <%= f.text_field :present %>
        <%= f.text_field :stem %>
        <%= f.text_field :secondary %>
        <%= f.check_box :atype %>
        <%= f.text_field :comment %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Add to List" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

How do I define `Item`?

at localhost:3000 I get

> Expected /Users/user/Desktop/test/app/models/item.rb to define Item
>       Extracted source (around line #3):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have Item class definition in this file `/Users/user/Desktop/test/app/models/item.rb`, probably you don't...

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  #class definition goes here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are thinking wrong.**

You have an model in app/models/item.rb

for this you have an controller in app/controllers/items_controller.rb

and you have views in app/views/items/template.haml

if you want to do a form_for you do the form for a object. rails is looking what type of action you want to participate (new, update) and generates automatically the route (restful).

so you just gave an object to the form_for helper

```
#in view
=form_for Item.new do |f|
```

or

```
#in items_controller.rb
def new
  @item = Item.new
end

#in new.haml
=form_for @item
```